# Books on the visual/graphical aspects of geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, visualization

Are there any books providing a ***general*** overview of the visual/graphical aspects of geometry? For example,

- Tilings (e.g. hyperbolic) and tessellations
- Plane/space filling shapes/objects (e.g. Escher's solid)
- Polyhedra (e.g. zonohedra, star/stellated polyhedra)
- Fractals and Lindenmayer systems
- Projections of polytopes (e.g. simplex splines)
- CAGD in general (e.g. spline curves/surfaces)

I'd prefer discussions/treatments from a mathematical perspective, though references from a more artistic point of view (such as the works by M.C. Escher) would also be appreciated :)

Comment: From the list you gave, the question is too broad.

Comment: @lhf The question is whether any such books exist (i.e. a general discussion, not focussing on a single topic). Can't be more concise.

Comment: _The Symmetries of Things_ (Conway, Burgiel, Goodman-Strauss)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textbooks for visual learners](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299876/textbooks-for-visual-learners)

Answer (score 4):

For a beautiful book on CAGD, see 
[Architectural Geometry](http://www.architecturalgeometry.at) by Pottmann et al.

[image]

For Lindenmayer systems, see [The Algorithmic Beauty of Plants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Algorithmic_Beauty_of_Plants) by Prusinkiewicz and Lindenmayer, now freely available.

[image]