# Visual approach to abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, visualization

I'm currently finding abstract algebra to be very fascinating. However, one of the things that pulls me back is that I sometimes find it hard to understand something visually.

For example, one could visualise the First Isomorphism Theorem as being a circle with a smaller circle inside (kernel) mapping to another large circle  with a dot (zero element), and the "annulus" left when you ignore the kernel is equivalent to the other circle, except for the dot.

I have a very amazing book Visual Complex Analysis, and was wondering if there's a similar one for abstract algebra.

Comment: Ted Shifrin wrote Abstract Algebra: A Geometric Approach (see https://books.google.com/books/about/Abstract_Algebra.html?id=8gMlAQAAIAAJ ). It might have some of what you're looking for. His section on Gaussian integers was helpful to me recently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textbooks for visual learners](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299876/textbooks-for-visual-learners)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For group theory see Nathan Carter's [Visual Group Theory](http://web.bentley.edu/empl/c/ncarter/vgt/) and its accompanying software, [Group Explorer](http://groupexplorer.sourceforge.net).