# Every subgroup of cyclic group is cyclic,How do I visualize this fact graphically?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I want to visualize everything in Mathematics.Is there a way to visualize the theorem I stated above?Can it be represented graphically?I want to be very analytical in this topic.So please can anyone suggest a good visualization or a textbook that discusses such topics?
         I want a visualization for this particular theorem.

Comment: This should be covered by your previous question: [Can the concepts of abstract algebra be visualized as in analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253019/can-the-concepts-of-abstract-algebra-be-visualized-as-in-analysis)

Comment: I want particularly this theorem to be visualized by some means.

Comment: Please punctuate properly.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes.Can you suggest a visualization for the above theorem?

Comment: You may be interested in answers to [MSE questions 2487500](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2487500) "How can I visualise groups in Group Theory".

Answer (score 8):

Here's a geometric description of finite cyclic groups:

> A finite group is cyclic if and only if it is isomorphic to a finite group of rotations of the circle $S^1$.

For example, the cyclic group of order $6$ is isomorphic to the group of rotations of $S^1$ through the $6$ angles $\frac{2\pi}{i}$, $i=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Once you believe that this description of finite cyclic groups is true, or once you go to the trouble of proving that it is true, then here's a very simple "visual" proof that every subgroup of a finite cyclic group is cyclic: every subgroup of a group of rotations of $S^1$ is also a group of rotations of $S^1$.